# cuda - memory allocation crashes

Tags: cuda

Ok I am trying to allocate an array of structs on the gpu, and it crashes (gives the stopped working msg).

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct point_t {
int id;
float x, y;
} point;
```

this is a part of the cuda code:

```
    cudaError_t d_LoadPoints(point* points, int n , int chunkSize){  
        // Error code to check return values for CUDA calls
        cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

         int nBytes = n * sizeof(point);

        // Allocate the device input points array
        point* d_points;
        err = cudaMalloc((void** )&d_points, nBytes);


    if (err != cudaSuccess)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector points (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


    cudaMemcpy(d_points,points ,nBytes ,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    puts("memory allocated successfully");

}
```

I tried printing the first elements of the `points` array , as well as `n` and `chunksize` and it comes out correctly.

This is the point it seems to crash at (I disabled the rest).
it crashes regardless of the debug prints.

The only thing I can think of is the size.

`n` is 250,000 and `chunksize` is 64,000 which I was planning to allocate for 125 blocks with 512 threads each.

I have no idea if this is a good idea or not but this is a side topic since I can;t even reach the kernel call.

Answer (score -2):

Restarting visual studio fixed the problem